# It takes forever to start a build in Jenkins and to find an idle slave for it

Tags: jenkins, virtual-machine, jenkins-agent, esx

We are operating one Jenkins master and about 70 swarm slaves with various operating systems. All machines are virtual running on a VMware ESX server.

For some months we are faced with these issues:

- When you manually trigger a build using the web interface it takes about ten minutes for the build to be scheduled as waiting in the list.
- When the job finally is in the build queue, it takes another ten minutes for master to recognize there is an idle build node which can actually perform the build.
- Sometimes a node is shown busy in the node list, but when you look at it the job there is already done.

I cannot present what I've done before, since I have no clue where to start with this. I'm thankful for any clue where to look at or what to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What in the end made the difference for us was enabling LDAP caching like described [here](https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/235216188-The-log-in-with-LDAP-plugin-is-very-slow).

(Global Security => Advanced Configuration)

Answer (score 1):

This is far from an answer, but [this open issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-20046) is somewhat similar to what you describe.